# django 2.13 login_required build-in decorator doesn't work

Tags: django, login-required

i work on Django 2.1.2 and i wanted decorated my view base on class. I apply login_required decorator in path

```
path('', login_required(CredentialsList.as_view()), name='credentials-list'),
```

when i send request to CredentialList it responds normally, it does not redirect me to the login screen. whether I omitted something from the configuration

```
LOGIN_URL='login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'list/'
```

Comment: `LOGIN_URL` should be an absolute URL, e.g. `LOGIN_URL='/login/'`, or the name of URL patter, e.g. `'login'`. `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is the same.

Comment: Thank, i notice, i run this project on another enviroment ( another linux ) where everything work fine and i notice that this must be absolute. Thanks Alasdair

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use the LoginRequiredMixin or the decorator in your view. For example:

```
# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# For a class-based view
class CredentialsList(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):

# For a function-based view
@login_required
def credentials_list(request):
```

and for your url remove the decorator:

```
path('', CredentialsList.as_view(), name='credentials-list'),
```

Comment: You are right, but decorator on class in path is the simplest and faster way, now i think maybe yours is a better way, by the way, i have resolved reason (enviroment) and not resolved problem ( i don't know why enviroment) but I will probably have to create a new environment. 
Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

I run this project on another linux (ubuntu 16.04), where is another enviroment of course and everything work fine :|. I must check in home what was wrong, maybe must create another virualenv.
Thank you all for your help me!!!